# Creating custom AlertControl in DevExpress winforms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have a issue whit `AlertControl` from `DevExpress`, I just want to show the mail icon as the picture below.

[image]

There is no property that let me do this. Any hint-help? The current alert that I have is: [image]

PS: I don't mean the custom button.

Comment: Hi Juan! Did you checked the sample projects provided with the DevExpress. Sample project have some Outlook like application sample. There you can find the implementation of these alerts used in that sample application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it from Image property of the button that you have added and it can be set at design time in DX Image Gallery section. See below image to set the button image:
[image: Select image from gallary]

**From:**[DX Image Gallery in code and current skin](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T391300)

> You can find all the available image files here: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\DevExpress 15.2\Components\Sources\DevExpress.Images\

For alternate way to get the image, follow the reference links:
[Getting Skin Images](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ42445)
[How to get the animated gif image from WaitForm](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T316372)
[How to get skin images at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2966)